# Python code to connect cassandra using spark-cassandra connector

Tags: python, apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, spark-cassandra-connector

I have to read some csv files using spark dataframe and pro-process those data before write those data to cassandra

Now I am able to read and pre-process the data but write those data into cassandra have some problem

```
Spark version - 2.4.1
Python - 2.7
Cassandra - 3.11
```

I have tried with different version of spark and cassandra but I am not able to connect cassandra using `org.apache.spark.sql.write` package

```
def episode_of_care_to_cassandra():
    ec = episode_of_care[['master_id', 'start_time', 'end_time']].copy()
    ecare = sqlc.createDataFrame(ec)
    print(ecare.collect())
    print(dir(ecare))
    ecare.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
               .mode('append')
               .options(table="ecare", keyspace="utss")
               .save()
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting.. did you set `sparkConf` correctly?

Comment: I have spark cluster running in my local system so I have spark config as  `sc = SparkContext('local', 'testapp')`